# Unable to open document “pdf” odoo

Tags: odoo, wkhtmltopdf

Installed V8 on 14.04.01, when printing report it throws following message:

Unable to open document “file:///tmp/sale.report_saleorder-1.pdf”.

File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported

Any help is very much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Is this report customized ? If yes post the relevant code.

Comment: This might mean that you printed an empty report. Not that it had no data, but that there is an error in your report generation that is causing it to be empty. 

What are you printing and how are you printing it? Please post the steps to reproduce this error as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is due to broken wkhtmltopdf package.

You can try using commands below to install them -

First remove the broken wkhtmltopdf from your system.
using -

```
sudo apt-get purge wkhtmltopdf
```

Then try using the commands below -

```
cd /tmp/
```

then Download the recommended version of wkhtmltopdf for Odoo server, currently 0.12.1: -

```
sudo wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

then install the package using dpkg :-

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

To function properly we’ll need to copy the binaries to an adequate location:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
```